# Django redirect ends up with an infinite loop

Tags: python, django, rest, redirect

I have the following code in my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
re_path(r'^api/users/$', views_udf.users_list),
re_path(r'^api/users/([0-9])$', views_udf.users_detail),
re_path(r'^api/predictions/new', views_fp.create_prediction_link, name='new-path-prediction'),
re_path(fr'^api/predictions/{link}', views_fp.create_prediction, name='new-prediction'),
]
```

And the following code in my views.py:

```
@api_view(["GET"])
def create_prediction(request):

from datetime import date
today = date.today().strftime("%b %d, %Y")
prediction_text = create_prediction_text(today)
entries = Prediction.objects.all()
entries.delete()
prediction = Prediction.objects.create(prediction_text=prediction_text)
prediction.save()
current_entries = Prediction.objects.all()

serializer = PredictionSerializer(current_entries, context={'request': request}, many=True)

return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(["GET"])
def create_prediction_link(request):
    return redirect(fr'^api/predictions/{link}')
```

Done according to tutorials, redirecting ends up with an infinite redirect loop, which is weird given that:

1. The page redirects to a different page, not to itself
2. The view in the page in redirected page is different

Should I have a different link basis? If not, what is the reason for the infinite loop happening? Did I miss something crucial in my code being inattentive?

Found no similar questions here and on the web apart from intentional infinite redirect, ready to provide additional details

Comment: your `create_prediction_link` links to `create_prediction_link`... It definitely links to itself, also the `fr'^api/predictions/{link}'` makes not much sense. It will use a variable name link and use that as link...

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike So what should it be like if I want to redirect from prediction/new to prediction/{link}? I don't seem to get it :(

Comment: A variable link is defined previously as randint

Comment: but that means that this will be determined once, when you start the server, let's say it is for example 42, then from that moment one, you server will only accept `/42/` until you restart the server, then it will determine another number (`84` for example), and accept `/84`.

Comment: @WillemVOsupportsmodstrike true, this is merely a futile attempt to make a prototype of a multiple link generator for every user. Need to add user id there probably. The goal was to make a separate link per result generation.